# search functionality - netzke grid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, netzke

I am using netzke for one of my projects. When I checked the search functionality in netzke grid it is not working for foreign keys. I have even checked the demo application "Yanit" and the same error (unable to connect to server) happens there too.

Also I would like to know how we can remove action links from netzke grid. Please help..

Comment: The demo is working fine for me.

Comment: which is the extjs version you are using?

Comment: Did you tried "http://yanit.heroku.com/" or a local installation of yanit?. If latter please specify the versions of extjs and netzke you are using.

Comment: I tried the hosted version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in the upcoming netzke-basepack v0.8.3: https://github.com/netzke/netzke-basepack/commit/abd489ea983f8dba5731bee67c4d2a13d41830e5

You can also source netzke-basepack from master on GitHub.

For configuring the bottom toolbar, use the `bbar` config option, for example:

```
def configure(c)
  super
  c.bbar = [:edit, :add]
end
```

Comment: can you please give an example to remove action links (add,edit etc) from grid pannel

Comment: I also extended the documentation to reflect this: http://rdoc.info/github/netzke/netzke-core/Netzke/Core/Actions (see 'Using actions')

Comment: Great, I am sure all the netzke users are enjoying great support from you. Thank you.